# WebView number of matches

Tags: android, webview, findall

I am using "findAll" on a webview, it works correctly, but do not know how I can retrieve the number of matches for if greater than 0 to show a button in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAll%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns
>   : the number of occurances of the String "find" that were found

So if you use

```
int count = mWebView.findAll(searchString);
```

then `count` will hold occurrence of a searchString text in webview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work for me, even if I find a match always returns 0

Comment: this should work. Can you share your code? @MiguelFern.

Comment: have you got answer of this question ?

Comment: I'm also always getting 0 from `findAll()`. Looks like an Android bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since findAll has this nasty bug returning 0 even if it matches and the function is deprecated:

[findAllAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAllAsync(java.lang.String)) Seems to be the way to go.

Its a little more work though since you need to implement a [WebView.FindListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.FindListener)

The results returned through that are also structured a bit differently and more difficult to handle.

```
webView.setFindListener(yourFindListener);
webView.findAllAsync("some string")
```

What also can be tricky is delaying the search until the site is fully rendered which is another tricky topic on its own. (depending on the page and its JS usage)